# How to grant domain user access to network share via batch file?

Tags: windows, network-shares, cmd.exe

I am trying to grant access rights to a domain user in a batch file like this:

```
net share sharename=c:\dir /GRANT:\domain\username,FULL
```

But it fails. I can only grant rights to local users.
Is there a way to grant rights to domain users with *net share*? If not, how can I do so in a batch file?

Answer (score 2):

net share sharename=c:\dir /GRANT:domain\username,FULL

Comment: This is the exact command the author tried.  You simply removed the `/` from the domain path which does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

try user principal name format instead of logon name. It worked for me.

```
net share sharename=c:\dir /GRANT:username@domain,FULL
```

[User Name formats](https://docs.microsoft.com/cs-cz/windows/win32/secauthn/user-name-formats?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Totally works. E.g.   ... /grant:"Domain Users@MyDomain,Change"

Answer (score 0):

You must also send the command icacl which grants the user full permissions.

```
  icacls "C:\dir" /grant  computerName\userName:(OI)(CI)F
```

you can find the full documentation here

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls

Comment: no need for a batch file, simply send this command after or prior to sharing the folder